# Snakebite fails with Client mechanism is malformed

Tags: python, hdfs, snakebite

I am using the HDFSSensor in airflow, which somehow does not work, so I thought that there might be something wrong with snakebite. Therefore I tried running

```
snakebite -D ls /
```

in the terminal and it fails with the error

> Request error: javax.security.sasl.SaslException
>   Client mechanism is malformed

From some github posts, I saw that the error has something to do with the following lines from debugging, so I tried following the solutions that include installing some libraries but the error stays the same:

> DEBUG:snakebite.rpc_sasl:Available mechs: DIGEST-MD5,GSSAPI
>   DEBUG:snakebite.rpc_sasl:Chosen mech:

I am working in a conda environment and hadoop fs -ls works perfectly fine.